Loss function that penalizes errors more at low values
I am training Deep Learning models to predict the Remaining Useful Life (RUL) of certain devices. The RUL is an estimate of the time remaining until the device is expected to fail. Accurate predictions are especially critical when the RUL is low, as you have little time of reaction to plan maintenance or mitigate potential damages.
One limitation of traditional loss functions is that they penalize the magnitude of the prediction error uniformly, regardless of the actual RUL value. For example, the cases $(y,\hat y) = (90, 100)$ and $(y,\hat y) = (0, 10)$ would both result in an identical Mean Absolute Error (MAE) of 10. However, the latter case is far more critical and should be penalized more heavily.
To address this, I attempted to use the relative error as a loss function:
$$L=\frac{\mathrm{abs}(y-\hat{y})}{y+\epsilon},$$
where $\epsilon > 0$ is a small value to avoid division by zero. Despite this modification, the results were not satisfactory, and the model did not perform as expected.
Therefore, are there more effective ways to design a loss function that emphasizes errors at low RUL values?

Note that the MAE will elicit the median RUL, not the expected RUL, see here. I can absolutely imagine this making a bigger difference for the (typically implicit, see Kolassa (2020)) conditional predictive distribution if the conditional expectation is small. I am always skeptical about "adapting" the error measure to "emphasize" specific parts of the predictive distribution; I usually feel better about trying to find features that reliably distinguish this situation from others.

Many loss functions exist and there are multiple ways to create new ones. What exactly do you mean by 'more effective'? Additionally, how do you know an adapted loss will give you the 'performance' you expect?
